# How to extract action done by a program (controll panel client) to script in windows?

Tags: windows-10, script, control-panel, graphics-tablet, process-monitor

Frequently I have to make some changes in control panel using graphical applets. I'd like to know if there is any way to extract an action (for example the thing that is happening in system while toggling some switch) to a script or a program.

Exact situation where I need it is changing display mapping for my tablet. One click in application makes my tablet map to my second display. I'd like to make a script doing exactly this (or at least having the same effect for my tablet). I've tried to see what's going on under the hood using process monitor but I have no idea which of these actions could be the one I'm looking for. What tools could I use to examine it? Any idea of resources that could help me with this problem?

[Screenshot from process monitor with all actions captured after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIu4a.jpg)

Comment: I would recommend trying the methods from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275063/extend-my-windows-desktop-onto-this-monitor-programatically